# SQL - create table to store SQL user activity

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, monitoring, logfiles

I'd like to create a SQL table which stores/captures user access or activities for a particular database.

For example, a table which has an entry for username, database accessed/queried, activity time etc everytime a user logs into a server and queries a particular db.

I know there's the .txt log file somewhere I would look up - but is there an easier way of doing it automatically?

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can capture login activity in the SQL Server error log (turn on Login Auditing for "Both failed and successful Logins"):

```
USE [master];
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite 
  N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
  N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', 
  N'AuditLevel', 
  REG_DWORD, 
  3;
```

Or by creating a [LOGON TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) and using that to log to a specific table.

However since there are no triggers on `SELECT` statements, capturing all queries would require pretty intrusive methods such as a [server-side trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191443%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Logon Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) in SQL Server

Comment: That helps with login activity, but what about queries?